# Complex conjugate of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Does just replacing the $i$ ( $=\sqrt{-1}$ ) by $-i$ everywhere give the complex conjugate of any complex number of a function? Will that be the same as changing the sign of imaginary part of the finally computed complex value?

Comment: I think you are asking if  $f(\bar z) = \overline{f(z)}$ for all functions $f$. That's false.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Can you please clarify your question?  Can you give an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: I think the hidden question might be this: "Suppose $f(a + bi)$, where $a, b \in \Bbb R$, is written in the form $f(a + bi) = g(a,b) + h(a, b)i$, where $g$ and $h$ are real-valued functions of two real arguments. If we write $u(a + bi) = g(a, b) - h(a, b)i$, will $u$ be the complex conjugate of the function $f$?" Of course, once it's written this clearly, the answer is evidently "yes".

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z) = i z$. You're proposing writing
$$
g(z) = (-i) z
$$
and hoping that's the complex conjugate of $f$. Let's see it in parts. We have
$$
f(a + bi) = i(a + bi) = ai -b = -b + ai\\
g(a + bi) = -ai + b = b - ai
$$
But $\overline{-b + ai}$ is **not** $b - ai$, but is actually $-b - ai$.

So no, your proposed approach does not work, even for this very simple function.

Comment: You did it wrong. According to your definition of g(a+bi), it should be -ai-b only by replacing i by -i. So, it works here.

Comment: My definition of $f$ is $f(z) = iz$. There's **exactly** one $i$ in that expression. I negated it to get my definition of $g$. If that's not what "just replace the $i$ by $-i$ everywhere" means to you, then our problem is with **English** rather than mathematics. But you seem to already know the answer you want, so I'll just tune out here.

Comment: I expect the definition of g(a+bi) to be -i * zbar since I mentioned in the question that 'replacing i by -i everywhere'. So, if we define it like that does that work?

Comment: Ah...so your operation on $f$ *changes* depending on the way in which $f$ is written, even though the different forms define exactly the same function.  That's ill-defined, so ... you need to think more about expressing your question clearly and unambiguously.

Comment: BTW: saying "You did it wrong" isn't a very good way to get folks to want to help you; I say that as someone who's provided more than 3000 answers at this point.

Comment: Sorry for that @John Hughes

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what you mean is: Is $f(\overline z) = \overline {f(z)}$ for every function $f$ and every complex number $z.$ That is false. For example, suppose \begin{align}
f(z)=i|z|. \\[8pt]
\text{Then }  f(i)= i|i| = i\cdot 1 & = i \\[4pt]
\text{and } f(-i) = i\left|-i\right| = i\cdot1 & =i \ne -i.
\end{align}

However if $f$ is differentiable on its domain and its domain is an open set in $\mathbb C$ and $f(z)$ is real whenever $f$ is real, then $f(\overline z) = \overline {f(z)}$ for every complex $z.$

Comment: No, my question was not that. I have asked whether replacing i by -i 'everywhere', which does not mean only zbar. The function f may have 'i's at some other places as well.